# How to solve PostgreSQL index width problem

Tags: postgresql

I have a docker container which contains a PostgreSQL database. An application then connects to the database. In the database I have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS configuration (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    board BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES boards ( id ),
    date_time decimal(20,0) NOT NULL,
    version INTEGER NOT NULL,
    data TEXT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(board, date_time, version, data)
);
```

I am not explicitly creating any indices or any of the other meta-objects associated with this table.

The application used to be able to write to this table without problem, but now I am getting the following error:

```
Failure during 'insert_configuration_record': ERROR:  index row size 5992 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index "configuration_board_date_time_version_data_key"
DETAIL:  Index row references tuple (2,12) in relation "configuration".
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

It is possible that the PostgreSQL version changed at some point when I rebuilt the docker container, but I have not seen any messages refusing to load the database from the persistent storage or asking me to upgrade it. The current database version is `(PostgreSQL) 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)`.

It is possible that previously the data I was writing was short enough to not hit the limit.

How do I use "a function index of an MD5 hash of the value" to avoid this problem?

Comment: "I am not explicitly creating any indices*" - yes you are. `primary key` creates a unique index and the `UNIQUE` constraint creates another unique index. But why do you need to index `text` values? That sounds rather strange given the fact that such a value can be up to 1GB in size.

Comment: @horse I think you misunderstand the meaning of "explicit" as compared to "implicit". I am not EXPLICITLY creating an index. To explicitly create an index requires a command that specifically and explicitly creates an index. Specifying a primary key and a unique constraint IMPLICITLY creates an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had that unique constraint before with the same data, then you must have built PostgreSQL with a block size greater than the default 8kB.

Anyway, you should do that the hint tells you, and instead of the unique constraint create a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON configuration (
   board,
   date_time,
   version,
   md5(data)
);
```

You cannot turn this index into a unique constraint, because such a constraint can only be defined on plain columns, not on expressions. However, the behavior will be just the same as a constraint.

Comment: I did not rebuild PostgreSQL. I have never built it at all. I am using the Ubuntu packages. A website I saw suggested that adding a unique constraint was a two step process - first create the index and then add it as a unique constraint. Is this required with your code? If so could you please add to your answer how to use that index as a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: @AlastairG: a unique index and a unique constraint are pretty much the same thing. The major difference is, that a unique constraint can be defined as deferrable, but not a unique index.